# MongoDB connects with Node js locally but not on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

My database is on mlab. I can connect to it using resteasy or by using localhost but when i try to deploy this code on heroku i get application error. I dont get it what I'm doing wrong

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/client'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Genre =require('./models/genres');
Book =require('./models/books');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 61950));


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('pages/index');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

// Connect to Mongoose
    `mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:admin@ds161950.mlab.com:61950/bookstore');`
    `var db = mongoose.connection;`

```
    app.get('/genres', (req, res) => {
    Genre.getGenres((err, genres) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(genres);
    });
});
```

Comment: please mention the error message

Comment: Application error...after deploying on heroku

Comment: How can you tell the application error is connection error to mongodb?

Comment: Because after i connect to mlab...i get this error

Comment: Please mention the error msg. How can anyone possibly answer without given a error log. Please follow through for watching your log https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: And also please mention how model `Genre` is defined?? Is `getGenres` a getter??